# Foreman terminates after the whole process and doesn't run accordingly as defined in Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I am working on importing data from web based CSV into database, so I created a rake task that imports data into database. However I tried to make running my rails app a little seamless and I integrated the `import rake task` and `running rails server` into foreman.

However, when I run `foreman start`, the processes start but terminates after the rake task finishes. I also will like that rake task to start first before running `rails s`

Here is what I have done below:

**lib/tasks/web_import.rake**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

namespace :web_import do
  desc 'Import users from csv'

  task users: :environment do
    url = 'http://blablabla.com/content/people.csv'
    # I forced encoding so avoid UndefinedConversionError "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
    csv_string = open(url).read.force_encoding('UTF-8')

    counter = 0
    duplicate_counter = 0

    user = []
    CSV.parse(csv_string, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      next unless row[:name].present? && row[:email_address].present?
      user = CsvImporter::User.create row.to_h
      if user.persisted?
        counter += 1
      else
        duplicate_counter += 1
      end
    end
    p "Email duplicate record: #{user.email_address} - #{user.errors.full_messages.join(',')}" if user.errors.any?

    p "Imported #{counter} users, #{duplicate_counter} duplicate rows ain't added in total"
  end
end
```

**Procfile**

```
rake: rake web_import:users
server: rails s
```

**when I run forman start, the image below shows the process**

[image: process image]

I will like the `rake` task in the foreman to run first before running `rails s` command. I also don't want it to terminate by itself. I don't know what am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Or if I could define the precedence of which task starts first in foreman .. Procfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by refactoring the Procfile. Instead of having two tasks, I merged it to just one command using `&&` so I can determine which command takes the prefix and which one takes the suffix.

So I changed the profile to:

```
tasks: rake web_import:users && rails s -p 3000
```

With this I have my import run first and server command being the last.

If you noticed, I added port with `-p` flap so as not make sure server is listening on port 3000. Note adding port is optional.

I hope this helps someone as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add `&& until ! sleep 1; do sleep 1; done` to the end of any Procfile command that exits, thus forcing all the Profile's processes to terminate.

In other words, you keep the "process" that ran the command alive, forever.  It's not ideal, but for local development where you need some command to run, finish running, but not exit out of the Procfile's supervision, it can work.

Here's an example snippet of my procfile where I copy example config files to the locations where my redis sentinel processes need them to exist.

```
redis-sentinel-config: cp -f spec/support/config/redis/sentinel1.EXAMPLE.conf spec/support/config/redis/sentinel1.conf && cp -f spec/support/config/redis/sentinel2.EXAMPLE.conf spec/support/config/redis/sentinel2.conf && cp -f spec/support/config/redis/sentinel3.EXAMPLE.conf spec/support/config/redis/sentinel3.conf && until ! sleep 1; do sleep 1; done
redis-senitnel1: sleep 1 && redis-server spec/support/config/redis/sentinel1.conf --sentinel
redis-senitnel2: sleep 1 && redis-server spec/support/config/redis/sentinel2.conf --sentinel
redis-senitnel3: sleep 1 && redis-server spec/support/config/redis/sentinel3.conf --sentinel
```